# access public calendars from outlook in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, outlook

We need to design one ASP.NET (2.0 or 3.5) page where outlook public calendars to which user has access will be displayed. Exchange server version is 2003.

Was such kind of development done in past? Do we have any material/documents on it?

We need inputs on,
1. How to get public calendars (shared calendars) to which user has access?
2. What are the different kind of approaches and the best approach?

The requirements are of high level as of now. But wanted to brainstorm on the technical feasibility? any thoughts or comments would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're describing the "Outlook Web App" [(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Web_App](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlook_Web_App)), the very first AJAX application.  It should be included as part of your Exchange setup.

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install the Microsoft exchange server SDK 2007:
(you might have to click "Install" on the 2nd dialog to install a dependency program; then close the installer and start again)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2991

README:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server 2007 SDK\July 2007\readme.htm

.NET code samples for Microsoft Exchange 2007 SDK:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server 2007 SDK\July 2007\Samples\Autodiscover